# Defining a scope on User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, case-insensitive, sql-like

When searched for "john doe", I want to return users with names such as:

"john doe", "John Doe", "John Doe Jr.", "Mr. John doe" ...(and if possible "John Sr. Doe")

What I have done so far is that defined a named scope on my User model as:

```
scope :by_name, lambda { |name| where('UPPER(name) LIKE ?', name.upcase) }
```

And then in my /users/search:

```
name = params[:name]
@users = User.by_name(name).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

But this is not working. I am getting back users with exactly the same name and in a case-sensitive manner - so "john doe" returns if one exists a user with name "john doe". What do I need to do??

I am using MySQL with Rails 3.2.3.

Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
scope :by_name, lambda { |name| where('UPPER(name) LIKE %?%', name.upcase) }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scope :by_name, lambda { |name| where('UPPER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.upcase}%") }
```